# Why are Bayesian impulse response functions smooth?

Tags: bayesian, econometrics

Simple VAR IRFs are jagged, but every Bayesian IRF I've seen is very smooth. What's the intuitive reason for this?

Comment: The penalization induced by the prior. It pulls the parameters toward zero. Usually you also put tighter priors on distant lags, which adds to this fact as parameters decay in magnitude with the lag order.